# how to close an open slide presentation in google apps script without using saveAndClose and not ending the script

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf, google-slides

I have created some slides from a google sheet and now I have to make a PDF copy of the presentation. The slides came from responses to a google form. I have looked at several scripts from stack overflow that convert slides or slide presentations into PDF. The problem is all of them content this line.

```
 presentation.saveAndClose();
```

This line produces the error "saveAndClose is not a function".

I have tried separating them into two functions but what happened was I got several PDF copies of the template I used to create the slides instead of the slides with the data already in them.

Comment: About `This line produces the error "saveAndClose is not a function".`, what is `presentation` of `presentation.saveAndClose();` in your actual script? In order to confirm it, can you provide your whole script?

Comment: @Tanaike Consider adding a answer in the original post. You're right. `presentation`(i.e., `templateCopy`) is of type `File` rather than  of `Presentation` class.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. From your comment, I noticed that OP has already posted the same question by including a script. And, I posted an answer to the OP's previous question.